# Can't select dropdown list with selenium

Tags: java, maven, selenium

I have page with 1 text field and 2 select fields. When I select a value in the first dropdown this causes a postback and the second dropdown gets populated.

This works on 1 pc but not on the test server.

When I run my selenium maven tests on the test server I always get "Unable to locate element". I have tried with timers, fluent, implicit and explicit but no success.

Any ideas?

Comment: Could you share your code as well which have you tried so far??

Comment: ...and a link to the page and/or the relevant HTML.

Answer (score 1):

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(<Element Locator>));
```

There many options in ExpectedCondtions, select any as per your requirement. Here Element locator is your second dropdown locator id.

Answer (score 0):

@user3436977, I would like to use FluentWait in this situation. Here is an complete example of how to handle situation like that. I use dependent dropdown from a public webapp. In this logic, I am waiting on "State" dropdown until I get the option count greater than 5 ( this will prove that dynamic element are loaded in DOM).

```
@Test(enabled=true)
public void dependentDropdown(){
    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.get("http://phppot.com/demo/jquery-dependent-dropdown-list-countries-and-states/");
    driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
    Select country = new Select(wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.id("country-list"))));
    country.selectByVisibleText("India");

    FluentWait<WebElement> waitFor_state_list_population = new FluentWait<WebElement>(driver.findElement(By.id("state-list")));
    wait.withTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS).pollingEvery(1, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS).ignoring(NoSuchElementException.class);

    com.google.common.base.Function<WebElement, Boolean>  elementLoaded = new com.google.common.base.Function<WebElement, Boolean>() {

        @Override
        public Boolean apply(WebElement ele) {
            return ele.getTagName().equals("select")? new Select(ele).getOptions().size()>5? true: false: false;
        }
    };

    if(waitFor_state_list_population.until(elementLoaded)){
        Select state = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("state-list")));
        state.selectByVisibleText("Delhi");
    }

    driver.close();
    driver.quit();

}
```

Hope this will help.

Answer (score -1):

You can add delay after selecting first dropdown value using `Thread.sleep()`.

Comment: `Thread.sleep()` is not a good practice. You should instead use `WebDriverWait` so that you only wait the minimum required time.

Answer (score -2):

Always use Thread.sleep() for minimum for 3 second while you navigate from different different pages or select from dropdown and many more.

Comment: `Thread.sleep()` is not a good practice. You should instead use `WebDriverWait` so that you only wait the minimum required time.